# QMdiArea как отрисовать каждое окно

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qmdiarea

Мне нужно нарисовать в каждом субокне линейный график на основе массива "**mas**".
Попробовал в одном нарисовать выскакивают еще дополнительные окна (уже решил эту проблему).

**P.S.** Добавил `self.show()`, после чего перестали выскакивать ненужные окна.
Теперь пробовал через цикл рисовать каждое подокно перебирая `self.area[i]`,
зависает все.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMdiArea, QMdiSubWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtChart

mas =[1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.65, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 2.3, 1.5, 1.35, 2.52, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1,
              1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.7, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1,
              1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1]
x = len(mas)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
        for title in ["Data:1", "Data:2", "Data:3", "Data:n"]:
            mdiChild  = QMdiSubWindow()
            mdiChild.setWindowTitle(title)
            self.mdi.addSubWindow(mdiChild)
        self.mdi.tileSubWindows()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
        self.updateActiveChild(self.mdi.activeSubWindow())
        # install signal handlers
        self.mdi.subWindowActivated.connect(self.updateActiveChild)


    def updateActiveChild(self, subWindow):
        print("111111")
        self.area = self.mdi.subWindowList()
        self._chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.area[0].setWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.lay.addWidget(self._chart_view)
        self._chart = QtChart.QChart()
        self._line_serie = QtChart.QLineSeries()

        for i in range(0, len(mas)):
            self._line_serie.append(QtCore.QPointF(i, mas[i]))

        self._chart.addSeries(self._line_serie)
        self._chart_view.setChart(self._chart)
        self.show()





if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я переписал ваш пример, чтобы он работал правильно:

```
import random                                                             # +++
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMdiArea, \
    QMdiSubWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtChart


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, mas, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.mas = mas                                                    # +++
        
        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.mdi.tileSubWindows()  
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
        
        for title in ["Data_1", "Data_2", "Data_3", "Data_n"]:
            mdiChild  = QMdiSubWindow()
            mdiChild.setWindowTitle(title)
            self.mdi.addSubWindow(mdiChild)
            mdiChild.show()                                               # !!!

        self.area = self.mdi.subWindowList()
            
        for subWindow in self.area:
            self.updateActiveChild(subWindow)
            QApplication.processEvents()
            
    def updateActiveChild(self, subWindow):
        print(f"subWindow -> {subWindow.windowTitle()}")
        _chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()                                # self не нужен !!!
        widget = QWidget()                                                # ...
        subWindow.setWidget(widget)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        lay.addWidget(_chart_view)
        _chart = QtChart.QChart()
        _line_serie = QtChart.QLineSeries()

        if subWindow.windowTitle() != "Data_1":
            random.shuffle(self.mas)
            
        for i in range(0, len(self.mas)): 
            _line_serie.append(QtCore.QPointF(i, self.mas[i]))

        _chart.addSeries(_line_serie)
        _chart_view.setChart(_chart)
 
 
mas =[ 
    1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.65, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 2.3, 1.5, 1.35, 2.52, 1.77, 
    1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1, 1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 
    1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.7, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1,
    1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 
    1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1
]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow(mas)                                                   # +++ mas
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да спасибо работает. Только не понятно почему массив перемешивается. Первый элемент равен =1.33. На первой итерациии он соответствует, а на последующих непонятно как индексация идет. Это визуально по графикам видно, они должны быть одинаковыми.

Comment: @inquirer  уберите `if subWindow.windowTitle() != "Data_1":` и `random.shuffle(self.mas)` это  так, чтобы  визуализации, потому что в реалиях нет смысла во многих окнах показывать одно и тоже.

Comment: А понял. Как-то просмотрел этот момент) Как быть с тем же вопросом только на английском?